# UILabel Animation in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uikit

I'm trying to make an animation where the text gets moved to the bottom as it fades out, at the same time it reappears at in the same location as before and does the same animation. here my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.2f
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         productTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(381, 410);
                         productTextLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                         productTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(381, 340);
                         productTextLabel.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                     }];

}
```

my problem is I am trying to make this animation happen more than one time. I am using a for loop but it only does it once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the options UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat and UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse in the animationWithDuration: method to repeat and reverse the animation automatically.

The whole method will become:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.2f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse
                 animations:^{
                     productTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(381, 410);
                     productTextLabel.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL fin) {
                 }];
```

To cancel the animation you can call

```
[productTextLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Note: You should import QuartzCore to be able to call the removeAllAnimations function.

Answer (score 0):

try this way, it worked for me:

```
__block void (^fadePart1)() = ^{ productTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(381.f, 410.f); productTextLabel.alpha = 0.f; };
__block void (^fadePart2)() = ^{ productTextLabel.center = CGPointMake(381.f, 340.f); productTextLabel.alpha = 1.f; };
__block void (^fadePart1Finished)(BOOL finished) =  ^(BOOL finished) {
    if (_willFinishAnimation == false) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.2f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:fadePart2 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (_willFinishAnimation == false) [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.2f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:fadePart1 completion:fadePart1Finished];  
        }]; 
    }
};
fadePart1Finished(false);
```

I had a global `Boolean _willFinishAnimation;` variable, before I set the animation it was `false` and when I want to finish the effect I set it `true`, that is it.